# ClickOnce Updates and the Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, clickonce

If I build an application and let code first figure out where to put the database and the user inserts data via the application, will that data get lost on a click once update ?  If so, how do I approach this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: If you set up your EF migrations correctly then no data should be lost during the update.

Comment: I have used EF migrations before during the development phase.  Is it okay to use in my scenario (after release) ?

Comment: Yes, if you are making changes to your code then migrations will keep your models and database in sync. It might be harder to make some changes because after deployment you want to set the `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` to `false`, but it should work nonetheless. Look at phil's answer.

Comment: Each user will have a compact sql server file, so each individual install will have it's own local database.  Any caveats in migrations with this scenario ?  Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 3):

No there is No need to "lose" any data when using automatic migrations.
You migration config class should state **no data loss allowed**
You will need to build custom scripts/ or tweak the generated scripts when dealing with changes that result in data loss.

```
public override void MigrateDb() {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MYDbContext, MYSECIALMigrationConfiguration>());
       // Context = GetDefaultContext();  // check if a new context is really needed here 
        Context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

public class MYSPECIALMigrationConfiguration : MYBaseMigrationConfiguration<MYDbContext>{  }


 public abstract class MYBaseMigrationConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext  : DbContext{

    protected  MYBaseMigrationConfiguration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update

    }
```

> how to approach migrations.

.. Thats actual a big question.

[EF6 Migrations - new features and options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501)

[Great info on Migrations when working in teams.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501)
This covers many scenarios you may recognise and thus help you understand what approach suits you best.